# вставить символ в определенную позицию с конца строки в bash

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Не могу справиться с простой вроде задачей. В Bash имеется вывод неких команд в виде числовой строки. Требуется поставить точку в строку вывода в нужную позицию отсчитывая её от конца строки (например в 3).

```bsh
$ sum=15734092; sum=$((sum/102)) ; echo $sum

154255
```

Требуемый результат: 154.255

Пробовал разобраться с `sed 's/\(..\)$/\1./'` но так и не понял как ее сдвинуть, добавляется в конец строки 154255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пробовал разобраться с `sed 's/\(..\)$/\1./'` но так и не понял как ее сдвинуть, добавляется в конец строки 154255.

Просто перепутан порядок в выражении замены: сначала точка, а потом подстановка, а не наоборот:

```
sed 's/\(...\)$/.\1/'
```

Или в более приличном виде с расширенными регулярками и с числовым смещением:

```
sed -r 's/(.{3})$/.\1/'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это то что нужно)))